# How to generate a database with the EF model and SDF database?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, sdf

I'm using Visual Studio **Express** 2012 for Windows Desktop. I've just added an empty database (.sdf) with a model (.edmx). I've filled the model and hit the Generate Database From Model. That added a Model1.edmx.sqlce.

How can I run this file against my database? It displays as plain text...

Comment: 9-11-2013 20:09:36 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
9-11-2013 20:09:36 - Found installed product - Global Location
9-11-2013 20:09:36 - Found installed product - ssms
9-11-2013 20:09:36 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

Comment: Trying the tool! The script has error. How does the tool handle it?

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- NOTE: if the constraint does not exist, an ignorable error will be reported.
-- --------------------------------------------------

Comment: See my blogpost here re the broken script http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/02/fixing-entity-framework-designer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sql Server Compact Toolbox. Can be downloaded on [CodePlex](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases).

Answer (score 0):

I think, Visual Studio Express version doesn't rocognise .sqlce (SQL Compact Edition) files.
You need Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express.